# hidden system network traffic win7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, traffic

Long story short, my internet connection is always used to capacity by my laptop whether i'm using it or not.

nothing shows in performance monitor, no odd connections shown by `netstat -abn`

done everything an average user would do and then some. (updates off, virus scan, port scan, manually turning off services and processes)

tried wireshark but couldn't make anything from it, please advise on what software should i use or what could be eating my very limited bandwidth

Comment: Without more information we can't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Enable windows firewall and block all applications. Then enable one by one and find the program that is using the bandwidth. If even after enabling fire wall your usage goes up then your system may be infected with malware.